# How to prove the matrix is negative semidefinite?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Given a negative semidefinite matrix $A=\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}}$, and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sin(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_j)=0$. Let

$$B : = 
    \left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 \tiny\color{red}{-\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_1)}&0&\cdots&0&0&\color{red}{\tiny \cos(\theta_1-\theta_{n+1})}\\
 0&\tiny\color{red}{-\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_2)}&\cdots&0&0&\color{red}{\tiny \cos(\theta_2-\theta_{n+1})}\\
 \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
    0&0&\cdots&\color{red}{\tiny\color{red}{-\cos(\theta_{n-1}-\theta_{n+1})}}&0&\tiny \color{red}{\cos(\theta_{n-1}-\theta_{n+1})}\\
 0&0&\cdots&0&\tiny \color{red}{-\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_{n})} &\tiny \color{red}{\cos(\theta_{n}-\theta_{n+1})}\\ \hline
    \tiny \color{red}{\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_1)}     &\tiny \color{red}{\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_2)}   &\cdots&\tiny \color{red}{\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_{n-1})}&\tiny \color{red}{\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_{n})}   &\tiny \color{red}{-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\cos(\theta_{n+1}-\theta_{j})}
 \end{array}\right]$$

Is $C=A+B$ still negative semidefinite?

Comment: What makes you think that $C \preceq 0$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It is a guess actually. I should change the question, see the updated post. Thank you!

Comment: Did you perform some experiments, say, in MATLAB?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I wanted to, and I found it may exist so many combinations of $(\sin(\theta_{n+1}−\theta_1),\sin(\theta_{n+1}−\theta_2),\cdots,\sin(\theta_{n+1}−\theta_n))$. Any hint for numerically check? thanks!

Comment: That is what computers are for!  In 1 billion experiments, a failed experiment is enough.

Comment: There might be a nice approach involving the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).